# C++ server doesn't recognize AS3 socket

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, network-programming, network-protocols

Well, three questions in less then 24 hours.But I suppose the lack of any helpful documentation (that i can find anyway) gives me no choice.

now i know all about the security stuff adobes got going, the policy file deal and sandbox limitations that have to be juggled around. ive done the suggested options changes, allowing network access in my AS3 project. I got my server ready to spit the policy file out instantly upon connection; but the problem is flash/AS3 whatever you wanna call it simply doesn't see my server (or the other way around)

AS3 delays for a few seconds, like the documentation say it will if its struggling to make a connection/find the policy file, but it never makes a connection period, tries for a while and then gives up and spits me a access error (because it didn't find the policy file it assumes its not allowed on the network so it get mad at me for trying... lil stubborn buggers)

Flash never gets what its looking for, and my server never detects any connections (failed or succeeded, nothing) I know my server is good because i've tested it with a test client i wrote in C++ and they talk just like best friends.

So I'm pretty much and a loss for ideas now, I thought about re-creating the winsock classes in AS3, but i don't even know how the connect() function fro winsock actually works; i got the declaration, no definition for it that i can find.

I am not sure what you would really need from my source code, but there's over a thousand lines in the client alone already so posting it all isn't really an option. ill give here what i think is relevant at least.

```
function hwndEnterFrame(e:Event):void
        {
            //trace("Frame Entered");

            if (firstframe)
                {
                    trace("try to reconcile policy file...");
                    //Security.loadPolicyFile("192.168.1.2:843");
                    TSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.2",843);//must call flush() to send data***

                    firstframe = false;
                }
```

The Security.loadpolicyfile doesnt seem to do anything as far ive noticed, i get the same msgs with or without it, the code seems to be looking for the policy file at the location specified in the socket declaration. Everything compiles fine, it just ain't doing what i want it do :P everyone else seems to be writing their servers in Perl or Python i haven't found much of an abundance of C++ material, although from what i understand TCP is a universal connection across any platform that supports it (can cross-language without any funny-business)

meh, that what i got for now, if you want other parts of the code (client or sever side, whatever you want) ill stick it up here quick-like.

EDIT:

I found a swf online that i downloaded, it connected fine to the example server that came with it (but that server was written in c sparp so its not much use to me) but it wont connect to my server. So a known good flash client WONT connect to my C++ server, but a C++ client WILL connect to my C++ server. So its clearly somthing on the server side, becuase it dosnt hear any connection whatsoever from the flash apps (mine or the expamle one)

Cheers;
-Tyler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I needed to `AllowDomian(IPofserver)`. I thought I had already tried that but apparently not.